# Need an efficient way to find number of rows in a 2D list which has specific element in one of its coulmns

Tags: python, list

Say I have a 2D list(array) which looks like the below

```
[[1,'BUY',2015],
 [2,'SELL',2015],
 [3,'SELL',2015],
 [4,'BUY',2015],
 [5,'SELL',2015],
 ...
 ...
 ... n rows
 ]
```

Now, I need a piece of code to find the count of all the rows in the above 2D list whose second column is been assigned the value 'BUY'. I already have a code to do this  which looks like this.

```
cnt = 0
for row in list :
        if row[1] == 'BUY' :
            cnt = cnt + 1
print cnt
```

I need a more efficient way to do my job. Basically I am looking for a single line code to do this.

Comment: What makes you think that a single line of code is more efficient than a `for` loop? (spoiler: list comprehensions and builtin list operators *may* be more efficient because of implementation details in Python, but in either case, you are doing at best a linear search through the list).

Comment: Is this actually the bottleneck in your code? Have you profiled it?

Comment: The size of list sometimes may cross 10000 So I needed an effiecient. I thought Rather than using a for loop If there is any builtin methods It may help me reducing the time to find the count.

Comment: what ever you do, there will be always a loop at some point. The efficient way will be not traverse the list more than one time, or have is sorted and stop iteration on the first non 'BUY' element.

Comment: Using `%timeit` in an online iPython interpreter constructing a 2D list like so `data = [random.choice([[1,'BUY',2015], [2,'SELL',2015]) for _ in range(100000)]` and then `%timeit sum(int(ele[1] == 'BUY') for ele in data)` I got an average time of a whopping ~26ms. Hardly anything worth worrying about. Voting to close.

Comment: Thanks for the Info IanAuld

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sum()` on a generator to add the booleans of whether the relevant string is present:

```
cnt = sum('BUY' in item for item in lst)
```

Also, don't name your variable `list` or you'll mask the built-in function `list()`.

Comment: Thank for the answer. It still uses for loop Is there a way to do the same without using loops may be by using with some built in methods? The reason why is because the size of list some times may become greater than 1000.

Comment: Any built-in method would still have to look over each item in `lst`. There's no way to get this faster than O(n). Even looking through a million sublists like this would be trivial anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>>l = [[1,'BUY',2015],
 [2,'SELL',2015],
 [3,'SELL',2015],
 [4,'BUY',2015],
 [5,'SELL',2015]]

>>> len([i for i in l if "BUY" in i])
```

Comment: This why iterate across the sub lists with `in` instead of just checking the index where you know the value will be?

Answer (score 0):

What about this one:

```
count = len(filter(lambda x : x == 'BUY', list))
```

Comment: This works because the OP is using Python 2, but I would note that it will break in Python 3 due to `filter()` no longer returning a `list`. Also, it's probably a performance loss to go into a function for each entry and store an entire `list` for the results.

Comment: Oh, and it would need to be `x[1] == 'BUY'`. Also, use a name other than `list` (even though that's the name the OP uses in the question).

Comment: this is like a direction. The actual code must be written by person who asks the question :)

Comment: A) This direction is wrong, slow, and fragile. B) No, it's best for answers to stand on their own and actually work.